# Complex text index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have such property in my document

```
"Resources" : {
    "Data" : [ 
        [ 
            "ru.Title", 
            "Привет, Мир"
        ], 
        [ 
            "ru.ManualExcerpt", 
            null
        ], 
        [ 
            "ru.AutoExcerpt", 
            "Привет, Мир "
        ], 
        [ 
            "ru.Body", 
            "<p>Привет, Мир</p>\n"
        ], 
        [ 
            "en.Title", 
            "Hello world"
        ], 
        [ 
            "en.ManualExcerpt", 
            null
        ], 
        [ 
            "en.AutoExcerpt", 
            "Hello world "
        ], 
        [ 
            "en.Body", 
            "<p>Hello world</p>\n"
        ]
    ]
},
```

I need to created text index for each of these items. I have tried to do something like this

```
db.document.ensureIndex(
{
    "Resources.Data[0][1]": "text",
    "Resources.Data[1][1]": "text",
    "Resources.Data[2][1]": "text",
    "Resources.Data[3][1]": "text",
    "Resources.Data[4][1]": "text",
    "Resources.Data[5][1]": "text",
    "Resources.Data[6][1]": "text",
    "Resources.Data[7][1]": "text"
},
{ name: "text-index" }
```

But search is still not working. Is it possible to create index in my situation?

Comment: Define "not working". What happens when you try to do a text search?

Comment: It returns nothing..